# How do I make my error handling better?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pulling data that needs to have a column of ID values in order to match it with another data set. This ID number is located within a campaign name in the data set I am pulling in a column named 'Campaign' in a DataFrame. When I try and extract the ID number from 'Campaign' this list is shorter than the total entries of the DataFrame. I think that my error handling is to blame. An entry in 'Campaign' generally follows this format:

```
'CompanyAbbreviation_CampaignName_AccountNumber_ChannelNumber'
```

(it is this Channel number that I am trying to extract), however, some entries will be missing AccountNumber, ChannelNumber while other will have a full entry plus '_deleted'.

Here is my code:

```
ID = []
campaigns = frame['Campaign']
for cam in campaigns:
    try:
        blocks = re.split('_',cam)
        for block in blocks:
            if len(block) == 6 and block.isdigit() or 5 and block.isdigit():
                ID.append(block)
    except ValueError:
        ID.append(000000)
ID = pd.Series(ID)
#frame.index = ID
#frame['Channel_ID'] = frame.index
return frame, ID
```

Edit: Screenshot of some data
http://prntscr.com/8jck72

Comment: Maybe start with making your `if` statement act correctly, did you mean ... `or len(block) == 5`?

Comment: That's a good point..

Comment: so if len(block)==6 and block.isdigit() or len(block)==5 and block.isdigit()'?

Comment: More concisely `if len(block) in (5,6) and block.isdigit()`

Comment: Can you post dummy data in the appropriate layout and also dummy data in the appropriate target layout?

Comment: Added a screenshot of 'frame'

Comment: So I looked at all the 'unique' values in ID and it seems like my error handling isn't working at all as I found no '000000' in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Your `except` block never runs, as nothing you're doing in the `try` block will raise an exception as long as all the `cam` values are strings. If the "error" you want to detect is there not being a five or six digit number in the campaign string, you should put a `break` after the `append` call and use an `else` after the loop ends. The `else` block will be run if the loop ends without the `break` being hit:

```
for cam in campaigns:
    blocks = re.split('_',cam)
    for block in blocks:
        if len(block) in (5, 6) and block.isdigit():
            ID.append(block)
            break
    else:
        ID.append('000000')
```

I've also fixed the error in your `if` statement pointed out in the comments above, and also made the default `000000` value a string, rather than a verbose way of writing the integer `0`.